# Vue: V-modeled number selector not reflecting changed value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a number selector that allows you to select the frame you want an objects animation to start on. The start frame cannot be lower than 0, or higher than the maximum frames that exist in the object, so I wrote some code to validate and clamp the values.

The issue I'm having is that if I `console.log(this.object.startFrame)` the value is always printed as the correct clamped value, however when I click the up and down arrows on the number box, the value will increase/decrease indefinitely.

Object code

```
class Object{
    constructor(){
        this.frames = [/*some animation frames*/];
        this._startFrame = 0;
        /*...more properties*/
    }

    get startFrame(){return this._startframe}
    set startFrame(newFrame){
        this._startFrame = newFrame;
        //update cached frame buffer and stuff
    }
}
```

Vue number selector code

```
<input type="number" id="frameStart"  v-model="startFrame"/>
```

Vue computed property code

```
startFrame: {
    get(){
        return this.object.startFrame;
    },
    set(newFrame){
        this.object.startFrame = Math.max(Math.min(newFrame, this.object.frames.length - 1), 0);
    }
}
```

I tried moving the validation code into the Object's get/set methods, but Vue still won't show the clamped values in the number box.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the underscore for the input

```
<input type="number" id="frameStart"  v-model="startFrame"/>
```

And for getter and setter

```
startFrame: {
    get(){
        return this.object.startFrame;
    },
    set(newFrame){
        this.object.startFrame = Math.max(Math.min(newFrame, this.object.frames.length - 1), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, the code you posted is the exact same as the code in the original post. Was it supposed to be different? There is no underscore since `_startFrame` is a private property, and is only accessible through the public `startFrame` getter and setter